# How to add agents to a running MAS in Jason?

Tags: agent, multi-agent

I want to add new Jason agents to an existing MAS which is already running. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this question is being addressed in [Jason FAQ](http://jason.sourceforge.net/faq/#is-it-possible-to-addremove-an-agent-tofrom-a-running-mas). As it shows any other agent may create new ones using .create_agent internal action as bellow:

```
+a : true
   <- ... ;
      .create_agent(bob, "myAgent.asl");
      ... .
```